# Using public IP address in sockets

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am new to socket programming. My sockets work with localhost or local ip. But why can't I create a socket server with my public ip? When I try to do this in python, it complains "cannot assign requested address".

```
import socket
s=socket.socket()
host="address"
port=5000
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr=s.accept()
    result=c.recv(1024)
    print(result.decode('utf-8'))
    c.send("""
  test
""".encode('utf-8'))
    c.close()
```

My IP I got from this website:http://whatismyip.host/

Comment: Could you show how you determined your public IP address, and what the code looks like that tries to listen on that address? The problem might be that your computer is behind a router, and cannot listen on the address that belongs to the router.

Comment: I updated my question. I read from another post that my public ip belong to my router so I can't access it. But why can server machines access their public ip to build web servers then?

Answer (score 1):

A service like http://whatismyip.host/ will show you the public address of your router, that is the machine that is connected to the internet. If you look up the IP of your desktop machine, it will probably show something like `192.168.0.10`, with `192.168.0.1` being the address of your router that you enter in your desktop, as "gateway".

Your router resembles a firewall, separating your home network from the public internet.

In order to receive connections on your desktop machine, you would need to configure port forwarding on your router.
You will still have your python process listen on `192.168.0.10` (your local machine's IP). Or you could set it to `0.0.0.0` which is a shorthand for "all available interfaces".

Be aware that your public IP address is probably not stable.

Comment: Then does every machine in a local network have the same public ip then? Why can I connect to web server using its unique public ip?

Comment: Basically, yes. Since your Internet provider only gives you one public IP address, all the computers in *your* local network would be sharing that IP address. If you connect to another web server, your router will set its public IP as the source IP address of the packets, so that the replies can find the way back.